# Alternative to using final variables in java and android?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, final

Im having a problem with an app that I built that seems to be related to me using too many final variables in memory, when I test the app in android 2.3 and below it works fine but 4.0 and above it crashes after a while if the list gets too long, what im trying to figure out is a way that I can either bypass making the variables final or a way that can potentially make them null once they arent in view perhaps? below is my code, any help would go a long way thanks

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    final String url = (String) data.get(position).get(4);
    final String aviUrl = (String) data.get(position).get(2);
    final Date theTime = (Date) data.get(position).get(3);
    final String theTweetText = (String) data.get(position).get(1);
    final String theRealName = (String) data.get(position).get(0);
    final String theScreenName = (String) data.get(position).get(5);
    Boolean isRetweeted = (Boolean) data.get(position).get(6);
    final Long iD = (Long) data.get(position).get(7);
    final Integer totalTweets = (Integer) data.get(position).get(8);
    final Integer totalFollowers = (Integer) data.get(position).get(9);
    final Integer totalFollowing = (Integer) data.get(position).get(10);
    final Long tweetId = (Long) data.get(position).get(11);
    Date currentDate = new Date();



    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

    if (isRetweeted == true) {
        final String theRetweetedTxt = (String) data.get(position).get(12);
        final String theRetweetedUser = (String) data.get(position).get(13);
        final String theRetweetedImgUrl = (String) data.get(position).get(14);
        final String theRetweetedScreenName = (String) data.get(position).get(15);
        final Long rTiD = (Long) data.get(position).get(16);
        final Integer rTtotalTweets = (Integer) data.get(position).get(17);
        final Integer rTtotalFollowers = (Integer) data.get(position).get(18);
        final Integer rTtotalFollowing = (Integer) data.get(position).get(19);
        final Long rtTweetId = (Long) data.get(position).get(20);


        TextView theTweet = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tweet_text);
        TextView username = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.username);
        TextView realname = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.realname);
        TextView theTimeTv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.theTime);

        ImageView aviimage = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.user_avatar);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        ImageView retweeterimage = (ImageView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.retweeter_avatar);
        ImageView replyImage = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.mentionbutton);
        ImageView retweetImage = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.retweetbutton);

        RelativeLayout profileImageLayout = (RelativeLayout) vi.findViewById(R.id.profileimagelayout);

        profileImageLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Context context = v.getContext();
                Intent intent=new Intent(context, FriendProfileActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.putExtra("theuserid", rTiD);
                intent.putExtra("totaltweets", rTtotalTweets);
                intent.putExtra("totalfollowers", rTtotalFollowers);
                intent.putExtra("totalfollowing", rTtotalFollowing);
                intent.putExtra("useravatar", theRetweetedImgUrl);
                intent.putExtra("username", theRetweetedUser);
                intent.putExtra("screenname", theRetweetedScreenName);
                intent.putExtra("tweetid", rtTweetId);

                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Context context = v.getContext();
                Intent intent=new Intent(context, LightboxActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                intent.putExtra("thetweet", theRetweetedTxt);
                intent.putExtra("theimage", url);
                intent.putExtra("theuserid", rTiD);
                intent.putExtra("screenname", theRetweetedScreenName);
                intent.putExtra("tweetid", rtTweetId);


                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        replyImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Context context = v.getContext();
                Intent intent=new Intent(context, TweetScreenActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.putExtra("theuserid", rTiD);
                intent.putExtra("screenname", theRetweetedScreenName);
                intent.putExtra("tweetid", rtTweetId);
                intent.putExtra("isretweet", false);

                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        retweetImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {                   
                Context context = v.getContext();
                Intent intent=new Intent(context, TweetScreenActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.putExtra("theuserid", rTiD);
                intent.putExtra("screenname", theRetweetedScreenName);
                intent.putExtra("tweetid", rtTweetId);
                intent.putExtra("isretweet", true);
                intent.putExtra("thetweet", theRetweetedTxt);

                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        String str = (String) DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(theTime.getTime(), currentDate.getTime(),
                0L, DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_ALL);

        theTimeTv.setText(str);
        theTweet.setText(theRetweetedTxt);
        username.setText("RT by @" + theScreenName);
        realname.setText("@" + theRetweetedScreenName);

        imageLoader.DisplayImage(theRetweetedImgUrl, aviimage);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(url, image);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(aviUrl, retweeterimage);
        return vi;
    } else {
        TextView theTweet = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tweet_text);
        TextView username = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.username);
        TextView realname = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.realname);
        TextView theTimeTv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.theTime);

        ImageView aviimage = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.user_avatar);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        ImageView replyImage = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.mentionbutton);
        ImageView retweetImage = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.retweetbutton);

        RelativeLayout profileImageLayout = (RelativeLayout) vi.findViewById(R.id.profileimagelayout);

        profileImageLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Context context = v.getContext();
                Intent intent=new Intent(context, FriendProfileActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.putExtra("theuserid", iD);
                intent.putExtra("totaltweets", totalTweets);
                intent.putExtra("totalfollowers", totalFollowers);
                intent.putExtra("totalfollowing", totalFollowing);
                intent.putExtra("useravatar", aviUrl);
                intent.putExtra("username", theRealName);
                intent.putExtra("screenname", theScreenName);
                intent.putExtra("tweetid", tweetId);

                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Context context = v.getContext();
                Intent intent=new Intent(context, LightboxActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                intent.putExtra("thetweet", theTweetText);
                intent.putExtra("theimage", url);
                intent.putExtra("theuserid", iD);
                intent.putExtra("screenname", theScreenName);
                intent.putExtra("tweetid", tweetId);


                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        replyImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Context context = v.getContext();
                Intent intent=new Intent(context, TweetScreenActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.putExtra("theuserid", iD);
                intent.putExtra("screenname", theScreenName);
                intent.putExtra("tweetid", tweetId);
                intent.putExtra("isretweet", false);


                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        retweetImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {                   
                Context context = v.getContext();
                Intent intent=new Intent(context, TweetScreenActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.putExtra("theuserid", iD);
                intent.putExtra("screenname", theScreenName);
                intent.putExtra("tweetid", tweetId);
                intent.putExtra("isretweet", true);
                intent.putExtra("thetweet", theTweetText);

                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        ImageView retweeterimage = (ImageView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.retweeter_avatar);
        retweeterimage.setImageBitmap(null);

        String str = (String) DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(theTime.getTime(), currentDate.getTime(),
                0L, DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_ALL);

        theTimeTv.setText(str);
        theTweet.setText(theTweetText);
        username.setText(theRealName);
        realname.setText("@" + theScreenName);

        imageLoader.DisplayImage(aviUrl, aviimage);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(url, image);
        return vi;
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think final variables cause any issues. They are same like instance variables. My guess something else going wrong.

Comment: Please post the logcat from when the app crashes on 4.0+ devices.

Comment: I'm also calling shenanigans on final variables causing problems. Please post the logcat when you are posting about an Android app crashing.

Comment: Also, holy hell that's overly complex for a `getView()`. Please look up the ViewHolder design pattern and implement it for your own, and for your users' sake.

Comment: The logcat is telling me that I have an outofmemoryexception, the app holds alot of photos in memory, however the images are stored in a smart cache on the sd card and this has worked flawlessly on all devices under 4.0 but above it I get crashes, unfortunately I cant make the images smaller or the app will look terrible so somewhere somehow I need to figure out how im running out of memory, from looking around the web it seemed like the final variables may of been the issue, I will try to post the stack trace on here

Answer (score 3):

the 'final' keyword won't affect anything, it just basically tells the JVM that the value will not change, so your problem lies elsewhere.